# How can I use yield to paginate through?

Tags: python, rest

I am trying to get all records from a endpoint that uses pagination:

*From the documentation:*

#### Paging

Index actions are limited to 200 resources per request unless otherwise specified. A limit parameter may be supplied to reduce the number of results returned by a request, and an offset parameter may be supplied to skip records. Metadata about paging is returned in the index actions, for example:

```
{
  data: { ... },
  meta: { paging: { previous: '', next: '' } },
}
```

The previous and next fields will be URLs that can be used to retrieve the previous and next page of data, respectively. If there is no previous or next page, the field will be omitted.

So I am trying this:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta
import requests
import json

class Clio:
    API_BASE_URL = "eu.app.clio.com"
    CLIENT_ID = "aUX1h...MidAv"
    CLIENT_SECRET = "jGZZ...n49Ss"

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.auth()

    def refresh_token(self):
        # ...
        pass

    def get_matters(self):
        url = f"https://{Clio.API_BASE_URL}/api/v4/matters/"
        
        matters = self.fetch_data(url)
        yield matters

        while matters['meta']['paging']['next']:
            url = matters['meta']['paging']['next']
            matters = self.fetch_data(url)
            yield matters

        for matter in matters:
            print(matter['id'])

        return matters

    def fetch_data(self, url):
        response = self.session.get(url)

        return response.json()

    def auth(self):
        self.access_token = open("token.json", "r")
        self.access_token = json.load(self.access_token)
        
        if self.access_token.get("expires_at") < datetime.now().timestamp(): self.refresh_token()

        self.session.headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.access_token.get("access_token")}
```

The goal is to adapt the methods `get_matters()` and `fetch_data()` to return all matters when I call it from another file example.py:

```py
from clio import Clio

clio = Clio()

matters = clio.get_matters()

# ...
```

What is wrong in my class Clio?

Comment: I've not looked in any detail, but you can't return a value from a function that also has `yield`. (You can have an empty `return`.)

Comment: @alani Actually you can in recent Python 3.x versions but it wouldn't make sense here.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks.

Comment: I don't see what "yield" should help here. Better create a result object in which you collect all returned data from the pages (may be a list or you somehow concatenate page data to something). Use the while-loop to collect pages, pack them into result object and return it. Alternatively remove the "return" as Paul M. suggests.

Answer (score 0):

As @alani and @MichaelButscher mentioned, remove the `return matters` in your `get_matters` method.

The calling code needs to consume all items from the generator:

```
matters = list(clio.get_matters())
```